# Webpack - how can I merge/load .js files in specific order?

Tags: jquery, webpack

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this and I just can't seem to find one.

It's a simple (it seems) issue. I want to be able to merge .js files in the order they are appear in i.e. if I have this in my index.js (JSX), I would like them to be loaded in the order listed: -

```
require('script1.js');
require('script2.js');
require('script3.js');
```

However, no matter what I try, webpack seems to just load them in whatever order it wants. The obvious example of this is so I can load jQuery first to expose $ to preceding scripts. However, I would just like to know how to do this in general as I am building a rather complex app.

I hope this has not been answer somewhere before and I have missed it... this is driving me INSANE. I am used to work with Gulp SASS, which was so much easier.

If it makes any difference, I am using this with ReactJS/ReactDOM.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of how `require` (and ES2015's `import`, which Webpack also partially supports) works.

Instead of manually maintaining the order of your scripts, the point of `require`/`import` is to free you from having to do this manual maintenance of script order.

Instead, each script (module) declares its dependencies via `require`/`import`, and then the environment (Webpack, in your case) works out the dependency graph and ensures the files are loaded in the correct order (and in the case of true `import`, does clever things around live bindings).

Your jQuery example would work like this: Any of your scripts (modules) that requires jQuery does this:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

or

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

or similar.

That makes jQuery's main function available as `$` within that module. It also tells Webpack that that module requires jQuery. So it loads the scripts in the correct order to make that happen.

More in [the Webpack Introduction](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

Comment: A (belated) thanks for your response... had to take time away from dev but I am back on it now. Regarding what you wrote... does this apply only to the NPM install of jQuery? I have tried 'import $...' from a file in my scripts folder for jQuery slim but I am getting the $/jQuery is not defined error. Hoping this can help me better understand how Webpack makes function available.

Comment: @U4EA: I think there's some Webpack-specific configuration required which I'm not up-to-speed on.